# How to convert char to double in C?

Tags: c, char, double

I want to convert a char like "12345678901234567890.123 " to double,
so I use sscanf(str, "%lf", &d),
and I print it use printf("%20.3lf", d);

But I get the result is "12345678901234567178.000",

How can I fix it?

Comment: *a char like "12345678901234567890.123 "* -- that's not a char.

Comment: number of significant digits in the decimal of a `double` is about 16 orders of magnitude.(log10(2^53)≒16)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't, since you're trying to store a number with more digits of precision than will fit in your machine's `double` data type.

You need to use a big-number library, that "manually" computes with arbitrary number of digits and thus can go beyond the limits of your machine's basic data types.

Oh, and `"12345678901234567890.123"` is not "a char", it's called "a string".